# Using Regex to only accept x amount of a certain character

Tags: regex

I have this Regex pattern:

```
\b(?:[A-Z\d]+[\/\-])+[A-Z\d]+\b
```

And it collects everything I need perfectly, but then also grabs some things I don't want. I'm wondering how to write in there something like I do want to accept "-", but no more than 5 at a time. Same with "/" but maybe no more than 1 for those. Here's an example of what it's grabbing that I do want vs what it's grabbing that I don't want:

Yes:

```
AIR-CT2504-50-K9
1000BASE-T
ISR4451-X-SEC/K9
```

No:

```
0/1/10/5/50
2B108-250A-2B-2B-2B-250A-2B-2B-2B-250A-2B-2B
2022/10/28
```

Comment: How about `\-{1,5}`?

Comment: What tool or language are you using? This would probably be better done with two regex checks.

Comment: @PM77-1 [`\-{1,5}`](https://regex101.com/r/q7q54P/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want partial matches, you might use anchors and exclude a certain number of hyphens or forward slashes.

As the strings do not seems to contain spaces, and you can mix `-` and `/`:

```
^(?!(?:[^\s-]*-){5})(?!(?:[^\s\/]*\/){2})(?:[A-Z\d]+[\/-])+[A-Z\d]+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(?:[^\s-]*-){5})` Assert not 5 hyphens where `[^\s-]` matches a non whitespace char except for `-`
- `(?!(?:[^\s\/]*\/){2})` Assert not 2 forward slashes
- `(?:[A-Z\d]+[\/-])+` Repeat 1+ times matching 1+ chars A-Z or digits followed by either `/` or `-`
- `[A-Z\d]+` match 1+ chars A-Z or a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JTXdXF/1)